# Simple format of text on front-end of my website (replace characters)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My website uses product references in this style: "R202020"

I want them to be shown like this for the users of my website: "BA2202020"

So basically I'm looking for a script, which formats the style of my reference numbers (should affect a ".reference" class I've created) by:

Removing the "R" in the original reference - replacing it with a "BA2" in stead - leaving the rest as it is (the "202020" part).

How can I do this?

Comment: The duplicate has the answer to this question. It's looking for a comma, but you just need to change that to an `R` for it to work for you

Comment: Thanks. I am very novice in javascript, so please excuse me. I don't understand the examples given in that thread. It's about removing a character only, which is half of my problem - i still need to add the "BA2" part afterwards?

Comment: The second argument is what to replace the value with, so change `''` to `'RA2'`. A full example would be: `let new = oldValue.replace(/^R/, 'BA2');`

Answer (score 1):

Find 1st character of your string using `string[0]` and replace that with your desire value like below.

```js
var string=$('.YourClass').text();
var result = string.replace(string[0],'BA2');
$('.YourClass').text(result);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='YourClass'>R202020</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unless there is something i don't understand here - which is very likely as i am a novice in javascript - this piece of code will work only if the reference is "R202020" right? I need it to affect whichever reference, not just the R202020 example - as the references change from product to product. So rather than affecting a static refencenumber, i need it to affect a class (.reference).

Comment: See updated snippet using class to catch your value and set new value using class on  `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace method. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

```
'R202020'.replace('R2','BA2')  // BA202020
```

Comment: Thanks. But the R202020 is just an example - every product has a different refernece number - so i need a code which affects the .class not just a certain reference number (like for example R202020).